# git push not working, Getting "unpacker error"

Tags: git

My git push origin 'branch_name' isn't working, I'm getting "unpacker error". Here is the full error description:

```
$ git push origin dev
Counting objects: 778, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (202/202), done.
Writing objects: 100% (508/508), 557.77 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 508 (delta 339), reused 410 (delta 244)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (339/339)
error: unpack failed: error Missing tree c2d6988729bdf86654b6cbb50566286ae646bb55
fatal: Cannot receive pack: 
To ssh://mahbubul@192.168.1.102:29418/ringIDWeb.git
 ! [remote rejected] dev -> dev (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://mahbubul@192.168.1.102:29418/ringIDWeb.git'
```

I've googled and found some solutions but it isn't working for me. I've even got several answers in stackoverflow also for the quite same problem. So my question might be duplicate but the solutions aren't working for me.

So can you please explain what could be the reason for getting this error? and what could be the solution?

Comment: What questions/articles/solutions have you tried and didn't work? Please be specific. We don't like suggesting solutions you've already tried and failed.

Comment: git fsck
git prune
git repack
git fsck

Comment: someone said that it might be for stash is full. so clearing stash might help. which didn't help

Comment: I don't know why I'm getting negative vote. I've got a problem and mentioned with particular error in brief. so whats the problem with my question. I've already mentioned that it might be duplicate but solutions aren't enough for me. having agreed that situation I needed a suggestion on cause of error and a solution, and people are discouraging me to ask question by down voting. I don't get it. what I'm supposed to do for not getting down vote.

Comment: and someone said it might be a permission issue. so they suggested to give the permission. with "chmod -Rf u+w /path/to/git/repo/objects" but this can not be the issue as my other colleagues can push. if it was a permission issue then they could not push.

Comment: @ Madara Uchiha: I've mentioned the cases I've tried in my comments

Comment: How about trying `--no-thin`, from [here](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=1582)?

Comment: thanks --no-thin worked me